# How to Increase heap size in Java ME?

Tags: java-me, heap-memory, nokia, n95

Is there any way to increase the heap size for Java ME on a device?  I'm developing an application for a Nokia N95, but am bumping into memory issues when I try to do image processing of larger images.  The phone has plenty of heap space available, but seems to restrict the amount allowed to be used by Java ME to 1MB.

Comment: Can you give some information about the average size, both memory used and dimension, of the image files you need to process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Heap-size is hardcoded in device VM. If you are running out of memory you need to split you task into more smaller sub tasks to allow GC to kick in. With limited memory only limited operations are possible. You figure...

Answer (score 0):

On some J2ME handsets setting Midlet-Heap-Size jad attributes works. Say a handset has only 2MB heap, setting this jad attribute to say 3MB increases the Heap to 3MB. You can try this out, it worked on very few handsets for me though.