# Using -Xmx and -Xms in a JME application in a cell phone

Tags: java, memory-management, java-me, jvm

I've a JME application running in a samsung i617 cell phone, and the applications is throwing OutOfMemoryError when its heap goes over 7.1 MB (and the cell phone has 64 mb)...

Is it possible to use the -Xmx and -Xms parameters in JME

Comment: No you have no control over that like its Java SE counterpart

Comment: The phone may have a 64 MB storage capacity, but that doesn't mean you can use it in Java.  The storage capacity is like hard drive space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. Max heap size is device dependent. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348018/increase-heap-size-in-j2me).

The total memory of the handset is irrelevant. The JVM (or better the KVM) has only access to a part of it. The total amount varies from handset to handset. It could also be a restriction for the total memory a single MIDlet can access.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record WeakReferenecs are supported on CLDC 1.1 [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr139/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) (can't make comments yet, sorry...)

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`WeakReference`s](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and `WeakHashMap`s (e.g. on cacheable objects) to use as much memory as you can without throwing OutOfMemoryError. It adds some pain developing but provides a nice balance between memory usage and performance.

Comment: WeakReferences does not axist on JavaME as it is based on an older version of Java

Comment: Huh true, exists in J2ME-CDC but not in CLDC. My mistake.